# Understanding the usage of a theorem about cohomology of a compact Lie group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

We know that for $0\leq k\leq n$, the $k$-th de Rham cohomology group of the $n$-torus $\mathbb{T}^n = S^1 \times \dots \times S^1$ is
$$H^k_{dR}(\mathbb{T}^n) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n\choose k}.$$

I just saw a theorem:

> Theorem (Cartan-Eilenberg). For a connected compact Lie group $G$, its de Rham cohomology is isomorphic to the cohomology of the subcomplex of left-invariant differential forms on $G$.

Now I am trying to understand the following example (on page 138 of Morita's "Geometry of Differential Forms"):

> Since the n-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^n$ can be regarded as the $n$-fold product of $SO(2)$, it is a connected compact Lie group. Its Lie algebra is commutative and can be naturally identified with $\mathbb{R^n}$. Therefore, by the theorem, we have $$ H^k_{dR}(\mathbb{T}) \cong \bigwedge^k \mathbb{R^n} = \mathbb{R}^{n\choose k}.$$

This is confusing to me: when the Lie algebra is $\mathbb{R}^n$, the subcomplex of left-invariant differential forms on $\mathbb{T}^n$ should be the complex of differential forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$, because a left-invariant differential form is determined by its action on the Lie algebra. Then when we compute the cohomology of this complex, we should get the de Rham cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is very different from that of $\mathbb{T}^n$.

Could anybody point out my **mistakes** in the above reasoning? Thank you!

**Update:**
I just realized that to be left-invariant, the differential $k$-form must be an $\mathbb{R}$-linear combination of $dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_k}$.
So, forms like $f(x) dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_k}$ is not allowed if $f$ is non-constant.
Then, everything is in the kernel while only $0$ is in the image. Hence the result follows.

Comment: It seems that two different notions of cohomology are being conflated here: On one hand, we can consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a smooth manifold, and consider the complex of differential forms. On the other, we can consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be a vector space and consider the complex of alternating multilinear forms (with an operator $d$ arising from the Lie algebra structure). Only the latter is applicable here.